# Django Models. User - Marks

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to figure out the models on the example of a training site in Django.
Question:
Is it possible to make a "filter" in the model so that users from the Members table with the role of "teacher" come to T_Member?
Or is it not possible to do this at the model level?
second question: did i define the fields correctly? :)
Thanks to

There is a class "Users"

```
    student = 'ST'
    parent = 'PA'
    teacher = 'TE'
    SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (student, 'Student'),
        (parent, 'Parent'),
        (teacher, 'Teacher'),
    ]
 
    user_id = models.AutoField(verbose_name='User ID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', max_length=255, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='date of birthday', blank=False, default=date.today)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES, default=student )
```

and class Marks:

```
class Marks(models.Model):
    mark_id = models.AutoField(verbose_name='User ID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    d_of_publ = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата оценивания', blank=False, default=date.today)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, verbose_name='Subjects') 
    T_Member = models.ManyToManyField(Members, verbose_name='Teachers')
    S_Member = models.ManyToManyField(Members, verbose_name='Students')
    mark = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Marks', blank=False, default=2)
```

Comment: at first, you don't need add autofield. For T-Member you can setup field attribute limit_choices_to=your filter  (i can imagine limit_choices_to=Q(members__users__role='Teacher')) )

Comment: You haven't given details, but if you want to assign a role after creating it, you can try it this way.  `from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=# model)
def assign_teacher(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # assign teacher to t_member`

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can actually do is to override the save method of user model and whenever a new user has been created you just do whatever you want to do.
personally I don't recommend signals but that's your another option as well.

[django signals from django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/)

[django signals simple better than complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)

and with overriding save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self._state.adding:
       # DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
```